# C++ Typedef signature

Tags: c++, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I was looking through [this boost::multi_array example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_array/test/iterators.cpp) and it has a `typedef` such as:

```
template <typename Array>
...
typedef typename Array::template subarray<2>::type::iterator iterator2;
```

I understand what the

```
typedef typename <type> <new_type>;
```

signature looks like, but this has three things after the `typedef typename` and I can't find online what that would be called or what it does. Can somebody break down what that typedef does and why it has three things? I don't think it's boost-specific.

Answer (score 2):

The `template` in `Array::template` works exactly like the `typename` you already understand. Its role in the `typedef` is to tell (promise) the compiler that `subarray` is in fact a template and thus the `<2>` makes sense because of it.

This is exactly the same as the role of the `typename` keyword in that `typedef`, but with the effect of telling the compiler it's a `template` instead of a type.

Answer (score 1):

It is the old

```
typedef typename <type> <new_type>;
```

you already understand.

`type` is `typename Array::template subarray<2>::type::iterator`

`new_type` is `iterator2`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write a template function/class, the compiler sometimes needs some help. In this example, `Array::template` is a type inside of templated type, which makes it require the `typename`.

Without this need, that typedef would just be:

```
typedef Array::template subarray<2>::type::iterator iterator2;
```

However, this will (usually generate) a compiler error. To fix this error, simply insert the `typename` keyword.

```
typedef typename Array::template subarray<2>::type::iterator iterator2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `typename` is a helper in this case to let the compiler know this is a type.  The keyword is used in templates in instances where the compiler would have trouble choosing between a dependent type and a qualified type.